# Reverse row number Function

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to pass a row number in `data.table`, however, I would like to count in reverse based on a specific condition ("conv "in this case) where the condition of conv would be 0 and every event prior would be count -1 ordered by id.

```
id    group    event
1     a        click
2     a        click
3     a        conv
4     b        click
5     b        conv
```

Output would be like this:

```
id    group    event   num
1     a        click   -2
2     a        click   -1
3     a        conv     0
4     b        click   -1
5     b        conv     0
```

Comment: What if there is a row after "conv" ?

Comment: In my case, there shouldn't be one, but if there is, count positively (1,2,3, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `which.max` so in the case where there are two `conv`, the positive counting starts after the first. `seq(.N)` is equivalent to `row_number()` from `dplyr`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, num := seq(.N) - which.max(event == 'conv'), group]

#    id group event num
# 1:  1     a click  -2
# 2:  2     a click  -1
# 3:  3     a  conv   0
# 4:  4     b click  -1
# 5:  5     b  conv   0
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` alternative, assuming you would have only one "conv" per group. We can subtract the current `row_number()` by the index where "conv" is found in the group. This would also work when there are rows beyond "conv" in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(num = row_number() - which(event == "conv"))


#    id group event   num
#  <int> <fct> <fct> <int>
#1     1 a     click    -2
#2     2 a     click    -1
#3     3 a     conv      0
#4     4 b     click    -1
#5     5 b     conv      0
```